# Promonoidal categories as $S$-algebras

Tags: ct.category-theory, profunctors

A promonoidal category is a pseudomonoid in the monoidal bicategory $\bf Prof$, where the monoidal structure is given (on objects) by the product of categories.

I would like to show that promonoidal categories are, as a consequence, algebras for a pseudomonad $S: {\bf Prof}\to{\bf Prof}$.

My ultimate goal is to understand what is a co/lax/pseudo/morphism of algebras in this case, i.e. a "promonoidal profunctor" $p : B°\times A\to Set$ that "preserves the promonoidal structure".

I expect these two conditions to be equivalent:

1. $p$ is a pseudo-algebra morphism
2. $p$ induces a strong monoidal functor $\hat p : [A°,Set]\to [B°,Set]$, where presheaf categories are endowed with the Day convolution product.

If the promonoidal structure on $A$ or $B$ is representable, this is in turn equivalent to

3. The mates $p^\lhd : B° \to [A,Set]$ or $p^\rhd : A \to [B°,Set]$ are strong monoidal, if the codomain has the convolution monoidal product.

Suitably laxified, 2. and 3. define co/lax algebra morphisms for the same $\bar S$.

Using a general theorem about lifting monad to Kleisli categories of other monads, I can show that there is a lifting $\bar S : {\bf Prof} \to {\bf Prof}$ of the monad $S$ on Cat whose algebras are monoidal categories; but a $\bar S$-algebra seems to be just a multicategory, and not of the [particular kind](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/promonoidal+category#versus_multicategories) that corresponds to promonoidal categories.

> What am I missing?

Comment: I might have managed to get the extra structure from the definition of $\bar S$.